i try to change Go-Admin config but nothings change
I am facing an issue with the GO-Admin example. I have created a fork from the repository and tried to change the logo, but nothing seems to work. I need to see the changes made to the logo. Could you please guide me on this?
https://github.com/sinaw369/Go-AdminPanel
 cfg := config.Config{
     Databases: config.DatabaseList{
         "default": {
             Driver: config.DriverSqlite,
             File:   "./admin.db",
         },
     },
     UrlPrefix: "admin",
     IndexUrl:  "/",
     Debug:     true,
     Logo:      "<b>Go</b>AdminPanel", // change logo
     Language:  language.EN,
 }

 if err := eng.AddConfig(&cfg).
     AddGenerators(tables.Generators).
     AddGenerator("external", tables.GetExternalTable).
     Use(r); err != nil {
     panic(err)
 }


I believe that the logo should be GOAdminPanel, but what I see is still GoAdmin.

"tried to change the logo, but nothing seems to work"; please show us what you have tried and let us know what happened (i.e. info on any errors if any). Please include any relevant code in the question.

Sorry, I had added a GitHub link for more context and thought that would be enough.

Please extract a [mcve], it should allow you to find the issue yourself. Also, run the according code in a debugger. Just dumping a bunch of code here (or a link) and a vague description of "doesn't work" won't make a good question. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Your advice was invaluable. Thank you for taking the time to offer your insight.
